# AFNetworkReachabilityManager returns Reachable when not reachable

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

In my iOS application I want to monitor the reachability of multiple IP addresses in my network.

I was looking to create multiple `AFNetworkReachabilityManager` objects to monitor these IP's.

So I create the manager in the following way:

```
var server_address = sockaddr_in(
    sin_len: __uint8_t(sizeof(sockaddr_in)),
    sin_family: sa_family_t(AF_INET),
    sin_port: in_port_t(80),
    sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: inet_addr("10.0.0.60")),
    sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
);

item.reachabilityManager = AFNetworkReachabilityManager(forAddress: &server_address);
```

The `item` object has a property `reachabilityManager` which stores the manager and **does not run out of scope**.

After the initialisation of the manager, I set the `reachabilityStatusChangeBlock` for the manager in the following way, I also start the monitoring of the manager.

```
item.reachabilityManager!.setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock({ (status) -> Void in

switch(status) {
    case AFNetworkReachabilityStatus.NotReachable, AFNetworkReachabilityStatus.Unknown:
        NSLog("UNREACHABLE: \(item.name)");
    case AFNetworkReachabilityStatus.ReachableViaWiFi, AFNetworkReachabilityStatus.ReachableViaWWAN:
        NSLog("REACHABLE \(item.name)");
}

});

item.reachabilityManager!.startMonitoring();
```

if I perform a `reachable` right after the `startMonitoring()` it returns false, **which I expect**.

After that my `reachabilityStatusChangeBlock` is triggered and it tells me that the IP I am monitoring is reachable, while I know for sure it isn't (I am currently not even in the same IP range and a ping to that IP of course shows that there is no reply on the other end).

If I instantiate the `AFNetworkReachabilityManager` with an unknown domain name, it correctly returns the status. So I know the manager is working correctly.

The one thing I can imagine, causing this, is the `sockaddr_in` variable I create to use the manager, maybe I am messing up one of the parameters from the constructor somewhere?